# Change Error Bar Markers (Caplines) in Pandas Bar Plot

Tags: python, pandas, bar-chart

so I am plotting error bar of pandas dataframe. Now the error bar has a weird arrow at the top, but what I want is a horizontal line. For example, a figure like this:
[image]
But now my error bar ends with arrow instead of a horinzontal line.

Here is the code i used to generate it:

```py
plot = meansum.plot(
    kind="bar",
    yerr=stdsum,
    colormap="OrRd_r",
    edgecolor="black",
    grid=False,
    figsize=(8, 2),
    ax=ax,
    position=0.45,
    error_kw=dict(ecolor="black", elinewidth=0.5, lolims=True, marker="o"),
    width=0.8,
)
```

[image]

So what should I change to make the error become the one I want. Thx.

Comment: Format your code better and people might anwser your question

Answer (score 3):

Using `plt.errorbar` from matplotlib makes it easier as it returns several objects including the `caplines` which contain the marker you want to change (the arrow which is automatically used when `lolims` is set to `True`, see [docs](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.errorbar.html)).

Using `pandas`, you just need to dig the correct line in the children of `plot` and change its marker:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df = pd.DataFrame({"val":[1,2,3,4],"error":[.4,.3,.6,.9]})
meansum = df["val"]
stdsum = df["error"]

plot = meansum.plot(kind='bar',yerr=stdsum,colormap='OrRd_r',edgecolor='black',grid=False,figsize=8,2),ax=ax,position=0.45,error_kw=dict(ecolor='black',elinewidth=0.5, lolims=True),width=0.8)
for ch in plot.get_children():
    if str(ch).startswith('Line2D'): # this is silly, but it appears that the first Line in the children are the caplines...
        ch.set_marker('_')
        ch.set_markersize(10) # to change its size
        break
plt.show()
```

The result looks like:
[image: Resulting graph]

Answer (score 2):

Just don't set `lolim = True` and you are good to go, an example with sample data:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df = pd.DataFrame({"val":[1,2,3,4],"error":[.4,.3,.6,.9]})
meansum = df["val"]
stdsum = df["error"]

plot = meansum.plot(kind='bar',yerr=stdsum,colormap='OrRd_r',edgecolor='black',grid=False,figsize=(8,2),ax=ax,position=0.45,error_kw=dict(ecolor='black',elinewidth=0.5),width=0.8)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: but #1 I want the cap line on the error bar. #2 I want only the upper error bar not lower.

Comment: Perfect, I'm not sure if there's a way to do this(removing the arrows) using only `pandas` and `matplotlib`, you can set the caps using `capsize=5` in the `dict` arguments.

Comment: @nonickname No, I mean, if you are not setting `lolims=True`, you can use `capsize=5` for the caps to appear, however, I'm not sure how to get of the arrows.

Comment: well this doesnt help me. All these solutions i have tried before I posted this. I need the exact same shape. Thanks though.

Comment: I'd think of a solution creating the errorbars on another call, and then moving then behind (in z) the plot, that could work.